# moving a simple uploaded file to a new location

Tags: node.js, express

**What i am trying to do ::**

I am trying to move the uploaded file to `/public/images`

---

**My request**::

[image]

My **app.js** code

```
var express=require('express');
var mysql=require('mysql');
var fs=require('fs');
var http=require('http');
var crypto=require('crypto');

var app=express();

var connection=mysql.createConnection({
    host:'localhost',
    user:'******',
    password:'******',
    database:'*********'
});

connection.connect();

app.set('port',process.env.PORT||7002);

app.use(express.bodyParser());

app.post('/Details/',function(req,res){

    var file_name=req.files.key.originalFilename;
    console.log(file_name);

    crypto.randomBytes(8, function(ex, buf) {

        var array     = req.files.key.originalFilename.split('.');
        var type      = array[array.length - 1];
        var name      = buf.toString('hex') + '.' + type;

        fs.rename(req.files.key.path, './public/images/' + name, function(e) {
            next(e, name);
        });
    });
});

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'),function(){
    console.log('Express server listening on port'+app.get('port'));
});
```

---

**Error i am facing**::

```
next(e, name)......... "next" not defined
```

***How to resolve this ?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What exactly do you want to do? I think that instead of calling `next`, you want to generate a response back to the client.

So instead of this:

```
next(e, name);
```

Do this:

```
if (e) {
  res.send(500, e.message);
} else {
  res.send(WHATEVER_YOU_WANT_TO_SEND_AS_RESPONSE);
}
```

If you *really* want to call `next`, you need to add it to the callback function's argument list:

```
app.post('/Details/', function(req, res, next) { ...
```

Comment: Thanks ... this helps ! .... I have a another question.... ill make a new question for it :)